# How do I upload a X509 pfx certificate as a certificate to azure keyvault?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2

I have a couple of X509 certificates in pfx-format that I need to use in my applications to authenticate to other services. I want to have  these stored as certificates in a azure keyvault to get alerts if/when they expire, but I can not seem to upload them.

If I try to upload them using the web interface I get a error saying "can not upload certificate". If I try to upload them using azure CLI I get this error:

> We could not parse the provided certificate as .pem or .pfx. Please
>   verify the certificate with OpenSSL.

The certificates are working fine when using them in my applications. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

If I upload them as secrets I can then use them, but I loose the functionality of reminders of renewal that I want.

Comment: Did you use the self-signed certificate?

Comment: No the certificates I try to upload are provided by a 3rd party.

Comment: Which version of the Azure CLI and/or Azure SDK are you using? Does the PFX have both a public and private key? Are you using RSA or EC keys, and what hash algorithm are you using? Any details may help troubleshoot this better.

Comment: @klasmack did you find any solution or workaround for this? i have a .cer file from 3rd party, I installed it locally in my machine and was able use the certificate from my local store to call a webservice, but i am not able to import the same Azure keyvault and use it in my Service fabric app. Any leads will help?

Comment: Turns out that the certificate was exported with a password on it. I got the password from our IT and then uploaded again which worked fine. If you are exporting from the certificate from iis you need to use the password you select when exporting.